# MIDI sound only in one channel (left or right)

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I have an WPF application which need to play MIDI sound but only in one channel - on left or right headset channel.

I have a piece of a code that plays a MIDI note (in both channels), however I don't know how to modify it to play the MIDI sound ONLY on the RIGHT or ONLY on the LEFT channel.

This is my code:

```
public static class MidiNote
{
    public static MidiOut MidiOut = new MidiOut(0);
    public static void PlayNote(int key, int duration)
    {
        MidiOut.Volume = 65535;
        MidiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StartNote(key, 127, 1).RawData);
        Thread.Sleep(duration);
        MidiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StopNote(key, 0, 1).RawData);
    }
}
```

I found some partial answers but I do not know how can I use them. I read these two articles:

[Play sound on specific channel with NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248138/play-sound-on-specific-channel-with-naudio?rq=1)

[How to play sound only on the left channel of the headphone and only on the right channel of the headphone in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899783/how-to-play-sound-only-on-the-left-channel-of-the-headphone-and-only-on-the-righ)

Comment: What didn't work about the two examples you posted?

Comment: Class used in those examples is WaveOut while I am using MidiOut. I couldnt get WaveOut from MidiOut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using MIDI you have to send an appropriate MIDI message (a Control- Change or CC message) to the MIDI OUT device to tell it what PAN setting you want to use.

The PAN setting value should be in the range of 0-127 where:

- 0 = PAN HARD LEFT
- 127 = PAN HARD RIGHT
- 64 = PAN CENTER

I used your code as starting point and added a few methods to allow adjusting the PAN setting of the MIDI OUT device.

My example calls to demonstrate the PANNING are written as if it were a CONSOLE app but the new methods should work fine in your existing class / WPF application.

```
public static class MidiNote
{
    public static MidiOut MidiOut = new MidiOut(0);

    public static void PlayNote(int key, int duration)
    {
        MidiOut.Volume = 65535;
        MidiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StartNote(key, 127, 1).RawData);
        Thread.Sleep(duration);
        MidiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StopNote(key, 0, 1).RawData);
    }

    public static void SetPanHardLeft()
    {
        var panSettingHardLeft = 0;
        var cce = new ControlChangeEvent(0L, 1, MidiController.Pan, panSettingHardLeft);
        MidiOut.Send( cce.GetAsShortMessage() );
    }

    public static void SetPanHardRight()
    {
        var panSettingHardRight = 127;
        var cce = new ControlChangeEvent(0L, 1, MidiController.Pan, panSettingHardRight);
        MidiOut.Send(cce.GetAsShortMessage());
    }

    public static void SetPanCenter()
    {
        var panSettingCenter = 64;
        var cce = new ControlChangeEvent(0L, 1, MidiController.Pan, panSettingCenter);
        MidiOut.Send(cce.GetAsShortMessage());
    }

    public static void PlayNoteRightChannel(int key, int duration)
    {
        var panSettingHardRight = 127;
        var cce = new ControlChangeEvent(0L, 1, MidiController.Pan, panSettingHardRight);
        MidiOut.Send(cce.GetAsShortMessage());

        PlayNote(key, duration);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Plays using current setting (probably CENTER)
        Console.WriteLine( "Pan setting unchanged (should be CENTER)");
        PlayNote( 50, 2000 );

        // Set the PAN for the MIDI device to HARD LEFT...
        Console.WriteLine("Pan setting HARD LEFT");
        SetPanHardLeft();
        // ...and play the note again
        PlayNote( 50, 2000);

        // Set the PAN for the MIDI device to HARD RIGHT...
        Console.WriteLine("Pan setting HARD RIGHT");
        SetPanHardRight();
        // ...and play the note again
        PlayNote(50, 2000);

        // Set the PAN for the MIDI device back to CENTER...
        Console.WriteLine("Pan setting CENTER");
        SetPanCenter();
        // ...and play the note one last time
        PlayNote(50, 2000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. It works great. 
However there is still some quiet sound on channels. Even if I set PANNING to 0 then I still hear some sound in right channel. Is there any way to completely  mute one channel?

Comment: My suspicion is that any quiet 'artifacts' that you still hear in the channel that you are panned away from (the one that should be completely silent), would only be due to cheap MIDI hardware, allowing some bleed-over.  Consumer MIDI hardware in computers tends to be very cheap low-quality equipment.